# Array for string replacement working only with last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this code:

```
$(document).on('click','.submitMessage,.submitStdMessage', function(e){
    prevContent=$('textarea').val();
    alert(prevContent);
    variables = {
            '{nom}' : 'Manuel',
            '{apl}' : 'García',
            '{var1}' : 'chips',
            '{var2}' : 'deportes y aventura',
            '{var3}' : 'informática y tecnología',
            '{cst1}' : 'Serrano, 28',
            '{cst2}' : 'Plaza del carmen, 32',
            '{cst3}' : 'García Luna, 15'
        };

        $.each(variables, function (key, value) {
             newContent = prevContent.replace(key, value);
        });
        alert(newContent);
    });
```

When a string like this is passed:

> {nom}{var2}{cst2}{cst1}{cst3}

First alert says:

> {nom}{var2}{cst2}{cst1}{cst3}

Second alert says:

> {nom}{var2}{cst2}{cst1}García Luna, 15

If I change the order of elements inside the `variables` array, it always replaces the variable set on the last position of array. I need it to replace all variables send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `prevContent` **never changes**. You need to update it instead of another variable:

```
// Always declare local variables with var!!! 
var prevContent=$('textarea').val();
alert(prevContent);
var variables = {
        '{nom}' : 'Manuel',
        '{apl}' : 'García',
        '{var1}' : 'chips',
        '{var2}' : 'deportes y aventura',
        '{var3}' : 'informática y tecnología',
        '{cst1}' : 'Serrano, 28',
        '{cst2}' : 'Plaza del carmen, 32',
        '{cst3}' : 'García Luna, 15'
    };

    $.each(variables, function (key, value) {
         prevContent = prevContent.replace(key, value);
    });
    alert(prevContent);
```

Comment: Solved. I'll tick in 7 minutes. Very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

replace generally works with RegEx(you can check more information here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) so if you pass string as a parameter it will replace just one match.

You can use "mystring".split("wordToReplace").join("whatToReplaceWith");

Comment: This is a good point - those search patterns are going to be interpreted as regular expressions. In this case, the OP patterns will all work fine, but if one contained something like a `.` or a `*` there would be unexpected results.